# No ethernet ip address in my vocore2

Tags: bridge, openwrt

I just flashed my [vocore2u](https://openwrt.org/toh/hwdata/vocore/vocore_vocore2) with openwrt 18.06.1, and plug it with an ethernet cable to access network while setting up wireless access-point for my phone.
[image] 
The AP is working and connected to the network, but the ip in my phone is in the subnet of another router. And there's no ip assigned to my vocore2 so I cannot ssh into it. After connecting to vocore2 with serial terminal, ping 8.8.8.8 is also failed. 
How can I make my vocore2 gain ip from the router and setting up the network well?

```
    root@OpenWrt:/etc/config# ifconfig
    apcli0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr BA:D8:12:07:01:71
              inet6 addr: fe80::b8d8:12ff:fe07:171/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

    br-lan    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B8:D8:12:67:01:72
              inet addr:192.168.61.1  Bcast:192.168.61.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              inet6 addr: fd43:4277:1a20::1/60 Scope:Global
              inet6 addr: fe80::bad8:12ff:fe67:172/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:16891 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:2404 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
              RX bytes:1181826 (1.1 MiB)  TX bytes:477837 (466.6 KiB)

    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B8:D8:12:67:01:72
              inet6 addr: fe80::bad8:12ff:fe67:172/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:2773 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:736242 (718.9 KiB)
              Interrupt:5

    eth0.1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B8:D8:12:67:01:72
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:1067 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:145725 (142.3 KiB)

    eth0.2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B8:D8:12:67:01:72
              inet6 addr: fe80::bad8:12ff:fe67:172/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:1692 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:577096 (563.5 KiB)

    lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
              inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
              inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
              UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
              RX packets:886 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:886 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
              RX bytes:64988 (63.4 KiB)  TX bytes:64988 (63.4 KiB)

    ra0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B8:D8:12:67:01:71
              inet6 addr: fe80::bad8:12ff:fe67:171/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:27199 errors:14 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:2398 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
              RX bytes:2189856 (2.0 MiB)  TX bytes:441570 (431.2 KiB)
              Interrupt:6
```

network config

```
    root@OpenWrt:/etc/config# uci show network
    network.loopback=interface
    network.loopback.ifname='lo'
    network.loopback.proto='static'
    network.loopback.ipaddr='127.0.0.1'
    network.loopback.netmask='255.0.0.0'
    network.globals=globals
    network.globals.ula_prefix='fd43:4277:1a20::/48'
    network.lan=interface
    network.lan.type='bridge'
    network.lan.ifname='eth0.1'
    network.lan.proto='static'
    network.lan.ipaddr='192.168.61.1'
    network.lan.netmask='255.255.255.0'
    network.lan.ip6assign='60'
    network.lan_dev=device
    network.lan_dev.name='eth0.1'
    network.lan_dev.macaddr='b8:d8:12:67:01:72'
    network.wan=interface
    network.wan.ifname='eth0.2'
    network.wan.force_link='1'
    network.wan.proto='dhcp'
    network.wwan=interface
    network.wwan.ifname='apcli0'
    network.wwan.proto='dhcp'
    network.@switch[0]=switch
    network.@switch[0].name='switch0'
    network.@switch[0].reset='1'
    network.@switch[0].enable_vlan='1'
    network.@switch_vlan[0]=switch_vlan
    network.@switch_vlan[0].device='switch0'
    network.@switch_vlan[0].vlan='1'
    network.@switch_vlan[0].ports='0 2 6t'
```

Comment: Maybe you should give more details of what vocore2u is if you want help. Your question is the only one at U&L with this keyword...

Answer (score -1):

Fix by using following configuration:

```
network.loopback=interface
network.loopback.ifname='lo'
network.loopback.proto='static'
network.loopback.ipaddr='127.0.0.1'
network.loopback.netmask='255.0.0.0'
network.globals=globals
network.globals.ula_prefix='fd15:39fa:4166::/48'
network.lan=interface
network.lan.ifname='eth0.1'
network.lan.force_link='1'
network.lan.macaddr='b8:d8:12:67:01:71'
network.lan.type='bridge'
network.lan.proto='static'
network.lan.ipaddr='192.168.61.1'
network.lan.netmask='255.255.255.0'
network.lan.ip6assign='60'
network.wan=interface
network.wan.ifname='eth0.2'
network.wan.force_link='1'
network.wan.macaddr='b8:d8:12:67:01:72'
network.wan.proto='dhcp'
network.wan6=interface
network.wan6.ifname='eth0.2'
network.wan6.proto='dhcpv6'
network.@switch[0]=switch
network.@switch[0].name='switch0'
network.@switch[0].reset='1'
network.@switch[0].enable_vlan='1'
network.@switch_vlan[0]=switch_vlan
network.@switch_vlan[0].device='switch0'
network.@switch_vlan[0].vlan='1'
network.@switch_vlan[0].ports='1 2 3 4 6t'
network.@switch_vlan[1]=switch_vlan
network.@switch_vlan[1].device='switch0'
network.@switch_vlan[1].vlan='2'
network.@switch_vlan[1].ports='0 6t'
```